# Passing variable to jquery eq() function not working

Tags: jquery, for-loop, global-variables, blur

For every `tr` I want to get the difference between one `td` containing a `span` with text and another `td` containing an `input` box on focussing out of the `input` in the 2nd `td` with the script below:

```
$(function() {
    var tr_no = $('.unitrows').length;
    for (i = 0; i < tr_no; i++) {
        $('.samples2issue input').eq(i).blur(function() {
            var diff = $('.samples_available span').eq(i).text() - $(this).val();
            alert(diff);
        })
    }
})​
```

Problem is substituting the variable `i` with a number say `0` in the `var diff` computation works.But using the `i` in itself returns a -ve value. Meaning `$('.samples_available span').eq(i).text()` returns 0.

Could it be that since `i` is defined outside of the `blur()` function and it is not set   globally it is not picked when inside the `blur()` function.

Or how would I be able to replicate this using the `each()` function?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the code in the event handler is using the variable `i` after the loop has completed, so it will be one more than the index for the last element.

Use a closure to capture the value for the variable in each iteration:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tr_no; i++) {

  (function(i){

    $('.samples2issue input').eq(i).blur(function(){
      var diff = $('.samples_available span').eq(i).text() - $(this).val();
      alert(diff);
    });

  })(i);

}
```

Comment: This works thank you! The idea of using a closure new to me .. but brilliant. Thanks man.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply define `i` in global scope before `for` loop:

```
var i = 0;
for(; i<tr_no; i++){
    ...
}
```

Comment: That doesn't make a difference as the variable already is global, and it doesn't help because the value of the variable will not be the same when it's used in the event handler as when the event handler is bound.

Comment: @Guffa true, tried it and as you say value not passed into `i` variable inside the `blur()` event

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the html, but the clearer jquery would be this.

```
$('.unitrows').each(function(i){
  $('.samples2issue input').eq(i).blur(function(){
     var diff = $('.samples_available span').eq(i).text() - $(this).val();
     alert(diff);
  });
});
```

EDIT: I followed Guffa's advice and put the diff back in the event handler.

Comment: You would want to pick up the text and the value inside the event handler, otherwise you will get the value at the time the event was bound, not when the input has been changed. As the callback for the `each` method creates a closure for the index variable, it's no problem to use it inside the event handler.